# pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent getting called twice with VoiceOver

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility, uipickerviewdelegate, pickerview

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but when you select a picker view row with VoiceOver `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent` gets called twice.

Without voice over it gets called once.

I've tried this on a brand new project with bare bones implementation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: Voice over can send the same string multiple times, so check if it is doing that.

Comment: @Nitish it's happening with the most basic implementation. Here is a project where it is happening https://github.com/provmusic/PickerViewVOTest

Comment: @CodeBender I'm not sure how to test for that, can you please explain?

Comment: @Jared Would need to see some code to say where

Comment: @CodeBender ok, there's a sample project where it is happening here http://www.github.com/provmusic/PickerViewVOTest

Comment: Also, VoiceOver does not give proper index when we swipe the row. It always says "1 of #totlaNumber" no matter which row we swipe to. HAve you faced this issue?